# Error while updating VersionData field of ContentVersion object

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

When i am updating versiondata field of contentversion object it is throwing this error :
**You can't set the VersionData when IsMajorVersion is true.: []**

But IsMajorVersion field is also not writeable.

Has anyone got any solution for how to update versiondata field of contentversion?? Or any workaround for this?
Previsouly i was able to update this field but unfortunately it is not working now.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
My solution was to create the file from salesforce apex in the first place, with the majorversion set false, then update works.

here's an example that write a TEXT file
remember if its not text (for example if its PDF) the string you give it must be b64 encoded

```
 public string write_file(string filename, string file_txt){
    ContentVersion f = new ContentVersion();
    list <ContentVersion> flist = 
        [select id, title, ContentSize, PathOnClient, VersionData 
        from ContentVersion
        where title = : filename
        and FileExtension = 'txt' 
        and isMajorVersion = false 

        limit 1
        ];
    if ( flist.size() > 0 ){
        f = flist[0];
        f.VersionData = blob.valueOf(file_txt);
        update f;
    }else{
        f.title = filename;
        f.PathOnClient = filename + '.txt';
        f.VersionData = blob.valueOf(file_txt);
        f.IsMajorVersion = false;
    insert f;
    }    
    return('OK');
    }
```